# Get Output from a PS script and pass to a curl command

Tags: powershell, curl

How do I pass the output of a powershell script to update a parameter in curl command .

Example :

```
gci D:\temp | ? { $_.BaseName } | sort CreationTime -desc | select -f 1
```

If the output of the above command is a folder name ie xyz which corresponds to a "backup id" in below curl command .

```
curl -k -H "Cache-Control:no-cache" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -u "user:pswd" -X POST http://example.com -d "{"""abc""":["""def"""],"""ghi""":["""DATA""","""HISTORY""","""CONFIGURATION"""],"""backupId""":"""xyz"""}"
```

How can we use powershell to fetch the folder name  and update the backupid parameter in the above curl command and execute the curl  with the new updated backup id. In others other words if the output from powershell is 1234, it should update backupId of the .bat file running the above curl to be 1234 and get executed via task scheduler.

Comment: Why not use `Invoke-RestMethod`?

Comment: "*If the output of the above command is a folder name*" - it isn't, it's a `[system.io.directoryinfo]` object. You would need `select -f 1 -expandproperty name` (or fullname) to make it a folder name.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you're asking how to capture the output of a powershell command or script, then pass it to `curl` being invoked from a *batch file*. So you're really asking how to communicate with a batch file.

This depends on how the powershell script and the batch file are being called. Does the powershell script call the batch file? Does the batch file run the powershell script? Is some other program or shell calling both powershell and batch?

Depending on how this is all working, you could try:

- Saving the powershell output as an environment variable. Modify the batch file to read the environment variable contents as it invokes `curl`
- Writing the PowerShell output to a file. Modify the batch file to read this file and incorporate its contents into `curl` invocation.

Comment: I tried with below.First part get me the folder name for backup id.Second part holds the json under $opt and last part executes the curl command .
$backupID = Get-ChildItem D:\temp | % {$_.BaseName} | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$opt = "{"""dgcRestoreOptions""":["""CUSTOMIZATIONS"""],"""repoRestoreOptions""":["""DATA""","""HISTORY""","""CONFIGURATION"""],"""backupId""":"""$($backupID)"""}"
Invoke-Command {&curl -k -H "Cache-Control:no-cache" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -u "user:passwd" -X POST http://example.com -d $opt}

Comment: Unexpected token 'dgcRestoreOptions""":["""CUSTOMIZATIONS"""],"""repoRestoreOptions""":["""DATA""","""HISTORY""","""CONFIGURATION"""],"""backupId""":"""$($backupID)"""}"' in   expression or statement. + CategoryInfo:ParserError: (:) [], ParseException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: How do I use Invoke-Webrequest to avoid curl instead of below   :             Invoke-Command {&curl -k -H "Cache-Control:no-cache" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -u "user:passwd" -X POST https://example.com -d $opt}